# Creating MKMapRect from coordinates and using mapView.visibleMapRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkmaprect

I'm trying to see if some extents (max x, max y, min x, min y coordinates) I have are in the current visible map view.

I take my extents and create a `MKMapRect`:

```
MKMapPoint upperLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([boundary.extents.maxY floatValue], [boundary.extents.minY floatValue]));
MKMapPoint lowerLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([boundary.extents.minY floatValue], [boundary.extents.minY floatValue]));
MKMapPoint upperRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([boundary.extents.maxY floatValue], [boundary.extents.maxY floatValue]));

MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(upperLeft.x, upperLeft.y, fabs(upperLeft.x - upperRight.x), fabs(upperLeft.y - lowerLeft.y));
```

Now I want to check if my 'mapRect' is in the mapView.visibleMapRect:

```
if (MKMapRectContainsRect(mapView.visibleMapRect, mapRect)) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

But my extents are never contained by the `mapView.visibleMapRect` when I know they should be.

If I replace the `mapView.visibleMapRect` with `MKMapRectWorld`, then it will contain my extents 'mapRect'.

Am I doing something wrong? is `mapView.visibleMapRect` not what I think it is (the viewable area on the screen)?

Answer (score 1):

D'oh!

The issue was that I used minY instead of minX.

```
MKMapPoint upperLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([boundary.extents.maxY floatValue], [boundary.extents.**minX** floatValue]));
MKMapPoint lowerLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([boundary.extents.minY floatValue], [boundary.extents.**minX** floatValue]));
MKMapPoint upperRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([boundary.extents.maxY floatValue], [boundary.extents.**maxX** floatValue]));
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapView.visibleMapRect` is exactly what you think it is, the map rect displayed by your map view. The problem is probably that the `MKMapRectContainsRect` function only tells you if one map rect is entirely contained (completely enclosed) in another. It's likely that you just want to use `MKMapRectIntersectsRect` which just tells you that part of your map rect is inside your `mapView.visibleMapRect`

Comment: my mapRect is completely contained in the `mapView.visibleMapRect`. When I replace visible with worldMapRect, its there in the visible area.